# Best puzzles of 2021 Q1 (January - March)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the first quarter ( January / February / March) 2021?
>
> ---

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

> **Algorithmically selected "best of"**:
>
> - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2021 Q1](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2021&month=1#query-results)
> - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2021 Q1](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2021&month=1#query-results)
>
> **Best by votes/views:**
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2021 Q1](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2021/01/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2021 Q1](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2021/01/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2021 Q1](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2021/01/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

<sub>Q: Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>
<sub>A: Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>

<sub>Q: What's the point?</sub>
<sub>A1: To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
<sub>A2: To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
<sub>A3: To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

## [Honeycomb: a hexagonal grid of letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106268/honeycomb-a-hexagonal-grid-of-letters) by [Seren](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/73054/seren)

This question appeared just after the turn of the year, created by a user brand new to the site. If any 'probably low quality' alarm bells were ringing, they were soon silenced, smashed and thrown into a fire to burn away altogether...

Deusovi's answer revealed this puzzle - presented as a single instruction-less image - to be a thing of true puzzling beauty with an exciting solve path to deduce and follow. If ever somebody asks to be directed to a high-quality, challenging problem to work through, *this* is the puzzle to which I will direct them.

Creative, succinct, and highly satisfying - this is pretty much the perfect enigmatic puzzle...